# SQL - Database Hierarchy Structure

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I have a table with value like this

```
id | parent | folder_name
-------------------------
1  | 0      | Root
2  | 1      | NSW
3  | 1      | QLD
4  | 2      | Sydney
5  | 3      | Brisbane
```

from this table i want to get a folder with all parents until higher level. Example: folder_name = Brisbane

```
id | parent | folder_name
-------------------------
5  | 3      | Brisbane
3  | 1      | QLD
1  | 0      | Root
```

i want to use `JOIN` in sql not `CTE`

Any help would be great

Comment: Why wrong with a CTE solution?

Comment: If this is your assignment, then friend you need to check out google rather than asking on stackoverflow. Check [How to ask questions on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Anuj - Though I agree we are not supposed to answer/encourage when there is no effort present in the question, but I do understand that Recursive CTE's are not easy to understand for new comers.. May be we can show them how to get it done once..

Comment: @Pரதீப் Yes, I agree, but giving away the answer, isnt the right thing to do, Showing them the right learning material is the way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Recursive CTE` is what you are looking for

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT *
         FROM   Yourtable
         WHERE  folder_name = 'Brisbane'
         UNION ALL
         SELECT b.*
         FROM   cte a
                INNER JOIN Yourtable b
                        ON a.parent = b.id)
SELECT *
FROM   cte
```